# check if third party app was already opened

Tags: android

I would like to check if third party app was already opened.

I can open third party app if i know packagename.

like:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.thirdparty.package");
startActivity( intent );
```

Can i check if was already opened before? I this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it is running with:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procs = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo info : procs) {
    for (String pkg : info.pkgList) {
        if (pkg.equals("com.thirdparty.package")) {
            //running
            break;
        }
    }
}
```